# Magento 2 How to exclude Head Miscellaneous Scripts section from deferred?

Tags: javascript, magento2.3.0, google-analytics, head, google-tag-manager

I am using a free extension for defer javascript [Magento 2 Defer Parsing of JavaScript](https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript.html), which is working fine.

But when I am adding Miscellaneous Scripts  in magento admin from head section which is also showing in footer but I want this script in head tag.

So how can I exclude head Miscellaneous Scripts from deferred?

I am using magento 2.3.0

Below code is used in this extension:

**etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="meetanshi_deferjs" instance="Meetanshi\DeferJS\Model\Observer" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace Meetanshi\DeferJS\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        $active = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('deferjs/general/active', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if ($active) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Meetanshi\DeferJS\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Meetanshi\DeferJS\Helper\Data;


class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->_helper->isEnabled())
            return;
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        if (!$response)
            return;
        $html = $response->getBody();
        if ($html == '')
            return;
        $conditionalJsPattern = '@(?:<script type="text/javascript"|<script)(.*)</script>@msU';
        preg_match_all($conditionalJsPattern, $html, $_matches);
        $_js_if = implode('', $_matches[0]);
        $html = preg_replace($conditionalJsPattern, '', $html);
        $html .= $_js_if;
        $response->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace below code in Observer.php file

```
<?php

namespace Meetanshi\DeferJS\Model;

use Meetanshi\DeferJS\Helper\Data;

class Observer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    private $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    )
    {

        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('request');
        if (!$this->helper->isEnabled($request)) {
            return;
        }
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        if (!$response) {
            return;
        }
        $html = $response->getBody();
        if ($html == '') {
            return;
        }

        $conditionalJsPattern = '@(?:<script type="text/javascript"|<script)(.*)</script>@msU';
        preg_match_all($conditionalJsPattern, $html, $_matches);

        foreach ($_matches[0] as $key => $jsCode) {
            if (strpos($jsCode, 'googletagmanager.com') !== false) {
                unset($_matches[0][$key]);
            } else {
                $html = str_replace($jsCode, "", $html);
            }
        }

        $_js_if = implode('', $_matches[0]);
        //$html = preg_replace($conditionalJsPattern, '', $html);
        $html .= $_js_if;

        $response->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

this code is exclude the googletagmanager code , if you need to exclude any other script code than you just need to change googletagmanager.com word